# rxjs pipe and subscribe (on a Subject) in two separate steps not working as expected

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

This gives me a headache... following code does work as expected:

```
const s$ = new Subject<any>();
  s$.pipe(
      switchMap(
        x => {
          debugger;
          return myService.getSth();
        }
      )
    ).subscribe(x => {
    debugger;
  });
  s$.next();
```

Both `debugger` in the `switchMap` and `subscribe` part are hit.
But if I split it up (I would like to move the whole piping stuff into separate libraries), the debugger in the `switchMap` is not hit anymore, meaning the service in this particular example is not called:

```
  const s$ = new Subject<any>();
  s$.pipe(
      switchMap(
        x => {
          debugger;
          return myService.getSth();
        }
      )
    );

  // ...

  s$.subscribe(x => {
    debugger;
  });
  s$.next();
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `.pipe` on an observable (including a subject) doesn't modify what that observable does, but instead it produces a *new* observable. In your first example, you call subscribe on that new observable. In your second example, you do nothing with the new observable, and then you subscribe to the original non-mapped subject. With nothing referencing the new observable, it is lost.

Save the result of the `.pipe` to a variable, and then subscribe to that:

```
const mapped$ = s$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    x => {
      debugger;
      return myService.getSth();
    }
  )
);

mapped$.subscribe(x => {
  debugger;
});

s$.next();
```

Comment: Yep. RxJS Observables are cold by default, which is exactly what you don't want 99% of the time.